# Dicing entities by date in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple entity

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I store it with EF to a SQL database and all is fine. A sample of the data is shown here. A certain Code can have data for a given date but not for other dates.

```
| Date       |  Code  | Value  |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2016-10-01 |   AA   | .5     |
| 2016-10-02 |   AA   | .6     |
| 2016-10-03 |   AA   | .7     |
| 2016-09-30 |   BB   | .51    |
| 2016-10-02 |   BB   | .64    |
| 2016-10-04 |   BB   | .75    |
| 2016-09-30 |   CC   | .51    |
```

Now I am wondering, what is the best way to retrieve the data so that I can have a result that include all dates in a given range? So that it looks like this:

```
| 2016-10-02 |   AA   | .6     |
| 2016-10-03 |   AA   | .7     |
| 2016-10-04 |   AA   | .7     | <<-- this is same as day before
| 2016-10-02 |   BB   | .64    |
| 2016-10-03 |   BB   | .64    | <<-- this is same as day before 
| 2016-10-04 |   BB   | .75    |
| 2016-10-02 |   CC   | .51    | <<-- this is latest available value
| 2016-10-03 |   CC   | .51    |
| 2016-10-04 |   CC   | .51    |
```

Basically the rule is that if for a day there is missing data, then I take the first day before that date.

The query requests data in a given date range and let's assume there is always at least an entity for a previous date in the database so whatever the query, I can always have a value for a latest available value.

I can get this information by means of several LINQ queries and some code but i wonder if there is a good approach I can take or even a SQL syntax that can help?

So far I am looping the dates in my range using the following query and method

```
public void CreateReportForDates()
{
   var dates = new [] { DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDay(-1) } ;
   var values = this.GetDataByDateRange(dates);

   .... do something with these values ....

}

public ICollection<MyEntity> GetDataByDate(EntityContext dbContext, DateTime date)
{
    var queryInDay = from element in dbContext.MyEntities
                     where element.Date <= date
                     group element by element.Code
                     into groupedElements
                     select groupedElements.OrderBy(x => x.Date).First();

    return queryInDay.ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetDataByDateRange(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
     foreach(var date in dates)
     {
         var dbContext = new EntityContext();

         foreach(var result in this.GetDataByDate(dbContext, date)
         {
            result.Date = date; 
            yield return result;
         }

         dbContext.Dispose();
     }
}
```

Comment: LINQ isn't really made for setting properties. You are going to have to write a method that does this work. Attempt to write the method and post your effort if you need help.

Comment: what do you mean by setting properties?

Comment: You are trying to set the properties of some new `MyEntity`.

Comment: Your logic dont look complete. Why `AA` lost day 1 and have day 4?

Comment: I thought it was clear. The table you see is what you have in the database. then **the rule is that if for a day there is missing data, then I take the first day before that date**. This is the nature of the problem. I cannot have data for every date but a report wants to see a complete set filling the gaps. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if it's possible with pure LINQ to Entities query, but even it is, it would be quite inefficient.

I would still use a mixed approach by getting only the necessary data from the database using a **single** query and expand the result in memory. For the expansion I would order the records by `{Code, Date}` (inside the database) and then use quite efficient iterative (non LINQ) approach:

```
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetDataByDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var dbContext = new EntityContext();
    var dbQuery =
        from g in (from e in dbContext.MyEntities
                   where e.Date <= startDate
                   group e.Date by e.Code into g
                   select new { Code = g.Key, MaxDate = g.Max() })
        join e in dbContext.MyEntities on g.Code equals e.Code
        where e.Date >= g.MaxDate && e.Date <= endDate
        orderby e.Code, e.Date
        select e;

    using (var result = dbQuery.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (bool more = result.MoveNext(); more;)
        {
            MyEntity next = result.Current, item = null;
            for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                if (item == null || (next != null && next.Date == date))
                {
                    item = next;
                    more = result.MoveNext();
                    next = more && result.Current.Code == item.Code ? result.Current : null;
                }
                else if (item.Date != date)
                    item = new MyEntity { Date = date, Code = item.Code, Value = item.Value };
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice. I like the fact that you start from the start date. so if i understand this correctly what you are after is the max date prior to the beginning date and then once you have that, you join for the other side. Definitely something to look at. I need to clean up the intra-day data points but I would say this brings me close to the solution. Let me work on it and i'll be back to you. Thanks